# Batch set variable to content of website

Tags: batch-file, web, cmd

I know that

```
set /p var=<some.txt
```

sets the var to the contents of a textfile.
But how can I get the contents of a webressource?

```
set /p var=<http://example.com/somefile.php
```

This is how it should work like. The PHP-File returns some generated text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `batch` **only** answer as it doesn't require third-party programs, VBS or any other stuff.

Basically you'll start with something like this - you download a file, set it to a variable and try to echo it.

```
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "MyTask" "https://xkcd.com/1678/index.html" "%cd%\content.html"
set /p content=<content.html
echo %content%
```

Well, not so fast. Batch doesn't like that unless the content is without special stuff it can actually interpret, therefore you need to make sure that the file doesn't contain batch commands or anything that could be interpreted as them.

For example if your file contains `<`, this is what you'll get if the content of the file is just `<missing.txt` (i.e. tries to load the content of a file that doesn't exist):

```
set /p nope=<file.txt
echo %nope%  # warning
```

**OR** you'll need to escape the content:

```
:: to make ! work (google what delayed expansion is)
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: fetch a file from that url
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "MyTask" "https://xkcd.com/1678/index.html" "%cd%\content.html"

:: clear the variable if available
set "content="

:: load content from file
for /f "delims=" %%i in (content.html) do set content=!content!%%i

:: echo with escaping special characters, keywords, etc
:: the bracket is really important here :)
echo(!content!

:: disable expansion
endlocal
```